# Converting Command line curl to PHP curl functions

Tags: php, curl

I am unable to convert this command line curl to php:

Structure

```
curl -X POST https://kanbanflow.com/api/v1/tasks -H "Content-type: application/json"
-d '{ "<PROPERTY_1>": <PROPERTY_VALUE_1>, "<PROPERTY_2>": <PROPERTY_VALUE_2>, ... "<PROPERTY_N>": <PROPERTY_VALUE_N> }'
```

Example in api documentation

```
curl -X POST https://kanbanflow.com/api/v1/tasks -H "Content-type: application/json"
-d '{ "name": "Write report", "columnId": "7ca19de0403f11e282ebef81383f3229", "color": "red" }'
```

I can't understand what is **-d** here? and how to pass data in this format.

so far i reach here but its not working.

### Updated Code

```
$data = json_encode(array('name'=>'Testing of api', 'columnId' =>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",'color'=>"red"));

$token = base64_encode("apiToken:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

$headers = array(
        "Authorization: Basic " . $token,
        "Content-type: application/json"
);

$url = "https://kanbanflow.com/api/v1/tasks";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
```

Suggest me where i am wrong..

### Update

I want to use https://kanbanflow.com api to add task

**Response:** `{"errors":[{"message":"Unexpected error"}]}`

Comment: `curl --help` to get info about params.

Comment: Thanks @RahilWazir but my code is not working and i don't want to run it though command prompt.

Comment: What do you get back in the response?

Comment: Whats not working? Could you explain what response you are getting.

Comment: Can you provide API documentation? Does curl example in your post work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution of my problem i was missing **swimlaneId** attribute. I am posting code here for future reference so it will help others.

Now sending data using object like following

```
$object = new stdClass();
   $object->name = 'Testing Task';
   $object->columnId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
   $object->swimlaneId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
   $object->color = 'green';

$url = "https://kanbanflow.com/api/v1/tasks";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($object));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Array of Json_encode is also working here

```
$data = json_encode(array('name'=>'Testing of api', 'columnId' =>"f648831061e111e3a41aa3dbd7a40406", 'color'=>'red', 'swimlaneId' => 'd0635fc061e711e3a41aa3dbd7a40406'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to json encode your data

```
$data = json_encode(array('name'=>'Testing of api', 'columnId' =>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",'color'=>"red"));
```

Comment: @manwal Still you say. Thats tricky. At least we can deduct the body for now. Can you try to get another error by screwing up your auth, maybe to try to rule out that. Since I see you left that out from your curl

Comment: My other requests are working @Cleric but only this one is not working. I haven't found any code example in Doc